# Pictures of equal size have different position when exchanged by the only command in a beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, graphics, positioning, overlays

I want to have the same basic slide with different pictures. For this I tried to use the only command. My minimal working example is

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Goettingen}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{My Example Frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item Text 1
\item Text 2
\item Text 3
\end{itemize}

\begin{columns}[C]
\column{.5\textwidth}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First
\item Second
\item Third
\end{enumerate}
\column{.5\textwidth}
\only<1>{
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Your_Picture}}
\only<2>{
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Your_Picture}}
\only<3>{
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Your_Picture}}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The goal is to have the pictures, which all have the exact same size, always in the same position.

Between the first and the second slide the position changes.

Any ideas or explanations?

Comment: Welcome! Why not `\includegraphics<1>{}`, `\includegraphics<2>{}` etc., which is designed for this?

Comment: You have spurious spaces in your use of `\only<.>{...}`. See [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](http://goo.gl/awJkj)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\includegraphics<1>{....}` or `\only<1>{%
\includegraphics{...}}%` Note the `%` at the end -- omitting leads to spurious whitespace causing the image to be shifted!

The `\only<...>{...}` version might be useful if there are more things to do than just to provide another image!

`\begin{column}[C]` is wrong, as far as I know!

```
\documentclass[12pt,demo]{beamer}
\usetheme{Goettingen}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{My Example Frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item Text 1
\item Text 2
\item Text 3
\end{itemize}

\begin{columns}
\column{.5\textwidth}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First
\item Second
\item Third
\end{enumerate}
\column{.5\textwidth}
\only<1>{%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Your_Picture}}%
\only<2>{%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Your_Picture}}%
\only<3>{%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Your_Picture}}%
\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear Christian,

Comment: Dear Christian,  thanks for the complete and precise answer! Some %s at the right place solve the problem and \includegraphics<i>... gives me a new option I didn't know yet. It naturally should be \begin{columns}[c] with a lowercase c to set the alignment of the column's content (although c is the default anyway).  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Never ignore errors when compiling. Substituting `example-image` for `Your_Picture`, I immediately get a compilation error complaining about the `C` in `\begin{columns}`. So let's change that to start with:

```
\begin{columns}
```

Minimising the example a bit:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{My Example Frame}
    \begin{columns}%
      \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{enumerate}
          \item First
          \item Second
          \item Third
        \end{enumerate}
      \end{column}%
      \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
      \only<1>{%
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}
      \only<2>{%
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}
      \end{column}%
    \end{columns}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

reproduces the issue. This makes it easier to see what is happening. A line break is a space. So, on the first slide, we have

```
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        {}
```

which will be understood as the image followed by two spaces, which TeX will collapse into the image followed by a single space.

On the second slide, we have

```
        {}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
```

which will be interpreted as a space followed by the image followed by a space. Since the image requires the full width of the column, it cannot be accommodated after the space and so a line break will be inserted before the image.

Commenting out the spaces by adding a `%` at the ends of the lines resolves the problem:

```
  \only<1>{%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}%
  \only<2>{%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}%
```

However, it is easier to use the overlay specification as an argument to `\includegraphics`:

```
        \includegraphics<1>[width=\linewidth]{example-image}%
        \includegraphics<2>[width=\linewidth]{example-image}%
```

Complete code for the minimised example above with fixes:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{My Example Frame}
    \begin{columns}%
      \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{enumerate}
          \item First
          \item Second
          \item Third
        \end{enumerate}
      \end{column}%
      \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics<1>[width=\linewidth]{example-image}%
        \includegraphics<2>[width=\linewidth]{example-image}%
      \end{column}%
    \end{columns}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I observe, that frames with some options require, that  `\begin{frame}[...]` and `end{frame} should be left aligned in editor (at least in WinEdt), i.e. without empty spaces before it. Otherwise arise error in file compilation (I don't know why).  So it is advisable to have habit always write them on such a way.

Comment: @Zarko That sounds most odd. My editor automatically places them as I've posted the code and I've never had a problem. Even if I move them left, they are likely to get re-indented by the editor. If this was really a problem, I'd have expected to run into it by now. Can you give an example of a case where you get an error? And which error do you get?

Comment: it's long time ago, when last time happen this to me. I foggy remind, that this happen with some options, probably with `fragile`, but I'm not sure now. I  will search my old presentation in `beamer`, and try to trigger this error. I will inform you (maybe as question) about my finding in near future.

Comment: I founded: the problem is option `fragile` With  `\begin{frame}[fragile]` and shifted `\end{frame} for four spaces to the right I receive the  error: `Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup`.

Comment: @Zarko I guess `[fragile]` frames are fragile ;). Definitely worth knowing - thanks for the info. I don't think I'm going to fight my editor over the non-fragile frames. Sometimes, you have to pick your battles and I think I'll reserve them for the `fragile` frames. Definitely a nuisance :(.

Comment: @Zarko Page 60 of the manual explains what `fragile` does: `To determine the end of the frame, the following rule is used: The first occurence of a single line
containing exactly \end{⟨frame environment name⟩} ends the frame. The ⟨environment name⟩ is
normally frame, but it can be changed using the environment option. This special rule is needed since
the frame contents is, after all, not interpreted when it is gathered.`